# How to make the Facebook log in take me to an activity?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-login

Hi guys i'm making an app that has the Facebook log in option, but i need it to take the user to the main activity (Which contains 4 fragments), i already made the log in work, but it stays in the activity where the log in button is located.
How can i make the Facebook log in button take me to the main activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) { 
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in..."); 
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
       Log.i(TAG, "Logged out..."); 
   }
}
```

There is in facebook sdk as any other sign in sdk a callback method of fail and success.

on success just launch ur main activity or finish the current one as u wish.